# Magento 2.4.3 Installs Complete but shows 404 on Localhost base URL

Tags: magento2, 404, magento-install

Following are the commands i run

```
~/www/magento2 > composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=root --db-password=Glassofwater_1 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=PKR --timezone=America/Chicago
```

http://localhost/magento2/ is point to `/Users/shanali/www/magento2`
It always show 404 error on apache2. I'm using Mac os monetory.

What do you suggest, i should perform in order to make it work.

Using PHP 7.4 and MYSQL 8.0 and ES

```
❯ php -v
PHP 7.4.26 (cli) (built: Nov 18 2021 15:28:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.26, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
❯ ❯ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 43
Server version: 8.0.27 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>


❯ curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "shanalis-mbp",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_shanali",
  "cluster_uuid" : "82jhI_yiScejAh62aO1XQA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.15.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "93d5a7f6192e8a1a12e154a2b81bf6fa7309da0c",
    "build_date" : "2021-11-04T14:04:42.515624022Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Following is the output of installation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you create virtual host?

Comment: if you do not want to create virtual host then simply just add pub in your secure url like yoursite/pub because the index file now resides inside pub

Comment: @RohanHapani how to create virtual office in macos big sur / monetry as there is no site-available folder exist in apache2?

Comment: https://www.rohanhapani.com/solved-404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation/

This may solve issue